# Can't get POST data because it's always null

Tags: php, angular, symfony, symfony-2.8

When I try to get POST data in Symfony 2.8 I keep getting `null`. I'm using an Angular service to make the call like this:

```
this.http.post(`****/app/relation/saveEmployeeWorkHours`, JSON.stringify({workHours}));
```

As you can see below, the payload of the data I am sending is visible:

[image]

In my routes I have this:

```
app_addEmployeeDays:
  path: /app/relation/saveEmployeeWorkHours.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: CompoRelationBundle:Api\Relation:saveEmployeeWorkHours, _format: 'json' }
  requirements:
    _method : POST
```

And in my action in the $request I get `null` for `POST` but I do get the get parameters I had sent in the URL (for debugging purposes):

```
public function saveEmployeeWorkHoursAction(Request $request){
    $response = $request->request->all(); // Gives array(0)
    $response = json_encode($response);
    $response = new Response($response);
    return $response; // Returns []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending your data/payload in the body of the request, not as individual parameters.

You need to access. `request->all()` retrieves the query and post parameters, not the body.

You need to do:

```
$body     = $request->getContent();
$response = json_encode($body);
// etc
```